# How do I Perform an API Call for each Item in a List

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reddit

I'm trying to get Price data for each company in a list of tuples `[(company_name, symbol)]`. In this instance I am using the TD Ameritrade API.

Also, I am having the same problem with Reddit. The only difference is I am trying to retrieve all the comments for each post 'id'. But, with the Reddit code I am pulling the ID from a pandas df instead of a list.

This is where I am at now:

- This is for the TD Ameritrade API

  ```
      async def run_app(symbols):
          # empty list to append dataframes to
          all_dfs = []
          for sym,name in symbols:

              # gets the price history data 
              rdata = asyncio.get_price_data(symbol=sym, period='10', periodType='day', frequency='minute', frequencyType='1')

              # prepares data for panda df
              can = unpack_ph_data(rdata, 'candles', 'symbol') 

              # function for creating a panda df
              df = create_ph_df(can) # function for creating a panda df

              # append to all_dfs
              all_dfs.append(df)

              return rdata
  ```

  My thinking was that using the for statement it would run each step **for** each item in the symbol list. First I tried without the `asyncio` then I saw an example similar to this but not with an API, so I figured I would try it.
- For Reddit:

  I am trying something similar using the `praw` package. But for this I am pulling data from each row in a pandas df and ran into the same problem.

  I have a function that gets a specified subreddit and returns all the data in a pandas df:

  ```
  def get_subreddit_data(subreddit="all", limit=25): 
      """
      :param subreddit: Which subreddit to get top posts. 
      :param limit: number of desired posts (This will be for setting the limit 
      after.hot(limit=num_of_posts)and eventually determined from user input. 
      Default 25

      :returns: top posts in subreddit or default (top posts on reddit).
      data is returned in pandas df with the following columns: 
      >>> title, score, id, subreddit, url, comments, selftext, created <<<
      """
      # empty list to insert data to: 
      posts = []

      # variable for data 
      top_posts = reddit.subreddit(subreddit).hot(limit=limit) # limit and subreddit params

      # FOR loop to append data to posts 
      for post in top_posts:
          posts.append([post.title, post.score, post.id, post.subreddit, post.url, post.num_comments, post.selftext, post.created])

      # Create df 
      df = pd.DataFrame(posts, columns=["title","score", "id", "subreddit", "url", "comments","selftext", "created"])

      return df
  ```

  `df = get_reddit_subreddit(subreddit, limit)` works fine and returns a pandas df

  This is where I run into issues:

  ```
  IDs = []
  for ID in [df["id"]]:
      IDs.append(ID) # Add IDs to ID list

  def return_comments_for(ID_list):
      # empty list to append comments to
      _comments = []
      """
      :param ID_list: list of post IDs 
      :returns: list of comments for each post ID 
      in ID_list
      """
      # for loop to extract each ID one by one
      for ID in ID_list:
          # Create submission instance
          submission = reddit.submission(id=ID)
          submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
          for comment in submission.comments.list():
              _comments.append(comment.body)

  comments = return_comments_for(IDs)
  ```

  That didn't work so I tried without creating a function and using a queue:

  ```
  # Empty list for all IDs
  queue = [] 
  IDs = [df["id"]] # get IDs from DF
  for i in IDs:
      queue.append(i) # Add IDs to queue 

  # list to append comments to
  _comments = []
  while queue:
      # pop item index 0 and assign to ID
      ID = queue.pop(0)
      # create submission instance for ID
      submission = reddit.submission(id=ID)
      submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)

      # for each comment in submission instance 
      for comment in submission.comments.list():
          _comments.append(comment.body) # append to main comment list
  ```

  This isn't the only way I tried to use a queue stack either. I have tried multiple different ways I just can't remember them all. But either way, none of them worked so I am missing something.

  This is the entire error message I get every time. No matter how I try it.

  ```
  ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-9-2cddf98f54ba> in <module>
       20 
       21 
  ---> 22 comments = return_comments_for(IDs)
       23 print(comments)

  <ipython-input-9-2cddf98f54ba> in return_comments_for(ID_list)
       14     for ID in ID_list:
       15         # Create submission instance
  ---> 16         submission = reddit.submission(id=ID)
       17         submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
       18         for comment in submission.comments.list():

  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py in submission(self, id, url)
      847 
      848         """
  --> 849         return models.Submission(self, id=id, url=url)

  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\praw\models\reddit\submission.py in __init__(self, reddit, id, url, _data)
      532 
      533         """
  --> 534         if (id, url, _data).count(None) != 2:
      535             raise TypeError("Exactly one of `id`, `url`, or `_data` must be provided.")
      536         self.comment_limit = 2048

  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
     1476 
     1477     def __nonzero__(self):
  -> 1478         raise ValueError(
     1479             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
     1480             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

  ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

```py
IDs = []
for ID in [df["id"]]:
    IDs.append(ID) # Add IDs to ID list
```

IDS is *not* a list of int, but a list of pandas.Series. Containing exactly one Series, namely `df["id"]`.

```py
# This does what you were trying to do:
IDs = []
for ID in df["id"]:
    IDs.append(ID)
    
# Which can be shortened to
IDs = list(df["id"])

# But I think just passing the Series to your function, should work fine:

comments = return_comments_for(df["id"])
```

The real bug is that `comments` will be `None` after this, because `return_comments_for` doesn't return anything, so it will implicitly return `None`.

Comment: Omg I can't believe I missed that.. passing df["id"] to the function worked, Thank you! I'm new to programming so I had a feeling it was going to be something simple that was right in my face but I couldn't figure it out.. Would using a version of that work with the TD Ameritrade function at the top? like if I was trying to pass a list of symbols I have chosen to a TD AMeritrade API to get all of their price history data, could I do something like pass the list at index 0 to the function, then after the function runs pop index 0 so it can start over again?

Comment: @CMWolfe `run_app(symbols)` expects `symbols` to be an Iterable of Sequences of length 2. I leave it as an exercise how you can create that from a dataframe. Try to think about what the types are of the variables the code is processing. It will make your understanding of what the code does a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The way you tried to extract a list of IDs is wrong, just do something like:

```
IDs = df["id"].values.tolist()
```